# Выравнивание сайта в зависимости от размера экрана в дюймах

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при одинаковом разрешении (в моем случае 1920х1080) но на разного размера экранах сайт отображается по разному (на меньшем неправильно - появляется полоса )(см. фото). Как это исправить и от чего оно идёт?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <div class="flex-container15">
      <div style="margin: auto;">
        <p>068 831-95-69</p>
        <p>050 824-61-74</p>
        <p>063 676-53-59</p>
        <p>044 334-31-80</p>
        <p>г.Киев, ул.Борщаговская, 152а</p>
        <p>Правый берег</p>
        <p>г.Киев, Харьковское шоссе,55</p>
        <p>Левый берег</p>
        <p>пн-пт: 09:00–18:00</p>
        <p>сб-вс: выходной</p>
      </div>
      <div style="margin: auto;"> <!-- верхняя панель -->
         <a href="index.html"><img style="margin: auto;" class="logo_img" src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <p>Заполнив форму заказа в не</p>
          <p>рабочее время офиса. Вы</p>
          <p>получаете дополнительно</p>
          <p>Скидку 7%</p>
        <div class="flex-container1166">
          <input type="text">
          <input type="text">
          <input type="text">
          <button>klass</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
        <div class="flex-container2" id="header_top"> <!-- панель навигации -->
            <div><a href="index.html">Головна</a></div>
            <div><a href="works.html">Наші роботи</a></div>
            <div><a href="sales.html">Акції</a></div>
            <div><a href="reviews.html">Відгуки</a></div>
            <div><a href="contacts.html">Контакти</a></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </header>
  <div class="line"></div>
        <div style="margin: auto; text-align: center;"> <!-- главный центральный текст -->
            <h1>Металопластикові вікна, двері, перегородки у Києві та передмісті</h1>
            <h1>Балкон під ключ</h1>
            <h1>Пряма доставка з виробництва безкоштовно в Києві та передмісті</h1>
            <p>Наша команда виготовляє, доставляє і встановлює металопластикові вікна та алюмінієві конструкції різного рівня складності:</p>
            <p>від вікон або дверей на балкон, до фасадних, офісних і торгових перегородок, тамбурів і веранд.</p>
            <p>Скління будинків, квартир, котеджів і дач</p>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%">
        <div class="flex-container" style="margin: auto;" > <!-- типы продукции -->
           <div class="specialize-cards">
            <div class="flex-container" style="margin: auto;" >
              <div style="margin: auto;">
                <h1 style="text-align: center;"><a href="dom.html">Засклити будинок</a></h1>
                <a href="dom.html"><img alt="" src="img/dom.jpg"></a>
              </div>
              <div style="margin: auto;">
                <h1 style="text-align: center;"><a href="teracce.html">Засклити терасу</a></h1>
                <a href="teracce.html"><img alt="" src="img/teracce.jpg"></a>
              </div>    
          </div>
        <div class="flex-container" style="margin: auto;" >
          <div style="margin: auto;">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;"><a href="kvartira.html">Засклити квартиру</a></h1>
            <a href="kvartira.html"><img alt="" src="img/kvartira.jpg"></a>
          </div>
          <div style="margin: auto;">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;"><a href="balconyonkey.html">Балкон під ключ</a></h1>
            <a href="balconyonkey.html"><img alt="" src="img/balconyonkey.jpg"></a>
          </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="flex-container" style="margin: auto;" >
        <div style="margin: auto;">
          <h1 style="text-align: center;"><a href="peregorodki.html">Перегородки</a></h1>
          <a href="peregorodki.html"><img alt="" src="img/peregorodki.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: auto;">
          <h1 style="text-align: center;"><a href="tambur.html">Засклити тамбур, ганок</a></h1>
          <a href="tambur.html"><img alt="" src="img/tambur.jpg"></a>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container" style="margin: auto;" >
      <div style="margin: auto;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;"><a href="mp-door.html">Металопластикові двері</a></h1>
        <a href="mp-door.html"><img alt="" src="img/mp-door.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div style="margin: auto;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;"><a href="mp-okna.html">Металопластикові вікна</a></h1>
          <a href="mp-okna.html"><img alt="" src="img/mp-okna.jpg"></a>
      </div>      
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
    .flex-container {
          display: flex;
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
        }
        
        .flex-container > div {
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
          margin: 10px;
          padding: 20px;
          font-size: 30px;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
        }
        .flex-container2 {
          display: flex;
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
        }
        
        .flex-container2 > div {
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
          margin: 10px;
          padding: 20px;
          font-size: 30px;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
        }
        .flex-container15 {
          display: flex;
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
        }
        
        .flex-container15 > div {
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
          margin: 10px;
          padding: 20px;
          font-size: 30px;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
        }
        .flex-container3 {
          display: flex;
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
          
        }
        .flex-container3 > div {
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
          margin: 10px;
          padding: 20px;
          font-size: 30px;
        }
        .flex-container1166 {
          display: flex;
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
        .flex-container1166 > div {
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
          margin: 10px;
          padding: 20px;
          font-size: 30px;
        }
        .contact-flex {
          display: flex;
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
        .contact-flex > div {
          background-color: #FAFAFA;
          margin: 10px;
          font-size: 30px;
        }
        .sticky {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%
        }
        .sticky + .content {
          padding-top: 102px;
        }

        @font-face {
font-family: "Montserrat";  
src: url("fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf") format("truetype"); 
font-style: normal; 
font-weight: normal;
 }
@font-face{
font-family: "Monserrato";
src: url("fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf") format("truetype");
font-style: normal; 
font-weight: normal; 
}
h1{
font-family: "Montserrat";
}
h2{
font-family: "Montserrat";
}
h3{
font-family: "Montserrat";
}
h4{
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  }
h5{
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    }
p{
font-family: "Monserrato";
font-size: large;
}
li{
font-family: "Monserrato";
font-size: large;
}
a{
font-family: "Monserrato";
}
body{
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
.logo_img{
  display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.padding-text{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.links{
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}
A {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
   } 
#content {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
   }
   hr {
    border: none;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 0px;
   }
   .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  hr {
   border: none;
   background-color: black;
   height: 2px;
  }


  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-right: 100%;
      justify-content: space-between;
      }
     html{
      width: 900px;
     }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-right: 100%;
      justify-content: space-between;

      }
      html{
        width: 950px;
      }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-right: 100%;
      justify-content: space-between;
      }
    html{
      width: 900px;
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-right: 100%;
      justify-content: space-between;
      }

  }
```

Там в ксс немножечко лишнего, не обращайте внимания)

[image: правильное отображение (фуллхд, 22 дюйма)]

[image: НЕ правильное отображение (фуллхд, 15.6 дюймов]

Comment: На первый взгляд, это треш какой-то, выкладывать фотки с экрана монитора, лол.
Я не думаю, что кто то будет детально в этом разбираться, но от себя хочу сказать, что проблема в адаптивной верстке.

Comment: А в чем проблема собсна? Наглядно показал различия на разных устройствах. Могу, конечно, и скриншоты показать но толку от того будет меньше.

Comment: Может на маленьком стоит масштаб больше у экрана.

Comment: Масштаб одинаковый (100%)

Comment: Ширина html у Вас указана в пикселях, в принципе результат соответствует вашему коду. У айфонов с шириной 1000+px а шириной вьюпорта 360px будет горизонтальный скролл так как вы указали ширину 900px для них

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что разные экраны имеют разную плотность пикселей при (возможно) одинаковом разрешении. Поэтому, когда вы задаёте ширину или высоту в пикселях, то по сути вы задаёте фактические размеры. Именно поэтому какой-нибудь блок с шириной в 1000px на телефонах с разрешением 2К+ будет вылазить за границы.

Ну а, собственно, чтобы страница одинаково хорошо выглядела и на ПК, и на телефонах, нужно сделать её адаптивной. Т.е. использовать относительные единицы измерения. И самая главная часть - медиа-запросы. Внутри медиа-запроса записывается блок стилей, который применится только если будет выполнено определённое условие (скажем, ориентация экрана - портретная). Подробнее про @media - [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Пример.

```
/* Выводит по одному .flex-item в ряд на экранах с реальным разрешением до 576px */
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .flex-item {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
}
```